# How do I select individual meshes?

Tags: select

I am creating my first objects following tutorials.

When I try to select the object on the picture, it selects the whole thing and I just want to select the individual cubes to transform them. When I click on it, it selects the whole thing. On the small person, it selects the individual cubes.

When I select the big object it even selects the torch on the hand of the small guy. How do I select individually the different meshes?

I know this is proper beginners question, but it's difficult to find the solution on google.

[image: Selecting the big object]

Thanks!

Comment: Switch to edit mode.

Comment: You're confusing meshes and object, an object can be made of several different meshes, here several cubes. As Ffeller says, if you select an object and switch to Edit mode, you'll be able to select the different meshes within this object and modify them. You can also extract one of these meshes and make it a different object if you select it and press P, or join the meshes of 2 different objects if you select them and press ctrl J, etc...

Comment: Yes, that was it, thank you!!!